# Exporting CSV with Numbers with different languages

Tags: mac, numbers, csv

I am exporting a file from Numbers to CSV and it contains language other than English, like Japanese or Russian.

After I export the CSV, all these funny characters shows up in the CSV.

Is there a way to fix that so Numbers can export as it is.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How exactly are you confirming that there are "funny characters"? I'm betting whatever you're opening the CSV in simply doesn't get the encoding right.

Comment: Exactly, once i exported from Numbers or Excel to a CSV file, I open the CSV, all these funny characters showed up instead Japanese or Russian.  How can "get the encoding right?"

Comment: How are you "opening" it? What application?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set the text encoding to UTF8